# How to set the 220x140 main image that appears on Chrome Webstore for extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

On the main Chrome Webstore Chrome extensions page (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) and when you search for an extension, there is a 220x140 image that appears next to each extension's listing.

I cannot determine where to upload/set that particular image size (its not an option under the screenshots or promo images when you edit your extension's listing on the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard).

Does anyone know how to set this particular image, as it's using my 128x128 icon image in place, which looks terrible and isn't what I want to show in that 220x140 space.

Comment: If you check the original image size it's actually 440x280, so I think it's the "Small promo tile" in Store listing settings. But I have the same problem, I have all promo images set and the extension listing is showing just the icon.

Comment: Yep same problem. I have the "Small Promo tile" set in the store listing (440x280) yet that image is NOT the one that appears when one searches for the extension and views it in the store listing.  Instead, the 128x128 icon gets shown (which looks bad in the store listing).

Comment: any update on this?